# How to prove any graph $G=(V,E)$ has a $k$-colorable subgraph with $\geq (1-1/k)|E|$ edges?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

I'm trying to find a way to prove that, for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and each simple undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, $G$ has a subgraph $H=(V',E')$ with chromatic number at most $k$ such that $|E^\prime|\ge (1-1/k)|E|$. I'm thinking that there is a way to prove this using the probabilistic method, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  I think you probably could use the probabilistic method on this.  It would probably go something like "randomly color ever vertex one of $k$ colors, and throw away any edges that are monochromatic."  This would give a valid subgraph with roughly $(1 - 1/k)|E|$ edges, but you'd have an error term to deal with.  So I might recommend this hint instead:  Start with any coloring of the vertices with $k$ colors, and then try to iteratively improve the coloring by recoloring vertices with a lot of the bad monochromatic edges.